# fancybox play swf file using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, flash, fancybox, swfobject

I am new in `.SWF` format file. I want to play swf file on click event using fancybox popup.
I tried to code for my requirment but `.swf` file not play in fancybox popup.
I entered direct url in browser its work properly but in fancybox popup not working.

[image]

Above screenshot of browser.
belowe screenshot is in fancybox popup.

[image]

Following `HTML` code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>SWF Playert</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $("a#inline").fancybox({
                'hideOnContentClick': true
            });
        });
        function swfplayer(swfUrl)
        {
            document.getElementById('swfparam').value = swfUrl;
            document.getElementById('swfembed').src = swfUrl;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="inline" class="btn" href="#data" onclick="swfplayer('http://example.com/demo.swf');">Video 1</a>
    <br />
    <div style="display:none">
        <div id="data">
            <object width="500" height="500">
                <param id="swfparam" name="movie" value="">
                <embed id="swfembed" src="" width="100" height="100"></embed>
            </object>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This swf file not playing in firefox browser.
Anything wrong in this HTML code ?